# Can't do API call from Module in WinForms

Tags: winforms

When my startup is Module, the api call just kills the application altogether. I need my entry point to be a module. How can i accomplish this?

```
Module EDIDownloaderModule

    Sub Main(args As String())
        ProcessApi()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub ProcessApi()
        Dim apiUrl As String = "http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/Projects/GetProjectByCustomerAndOrderIds?customerId=abc&customerOrderId=xyz"

        Dim apiResult As ApiCallResult(Of Project) = Await ApiCrudCallHelper.Get(Of Project)(apiUrl)
        Dim msg As String = apiResult.Message
    End Sub

End Module
```

When my startup is a form, i can do api calls without any issue

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ProcessApi()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub ProcessApi()
        Dim apiUrl As String = "http://localhost:3554/API/Projects/GetByCustomerAndOrder?customerId=abc&customerOrderId=xyz"

        Dim apiResult As ApiCallResult(Of Project) = Await ApiCrudCallHelper.Get(Of Project)(apiUrl)
        Dim msg As String = apiResult.Message
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here is the Helper code for the API calls

```
   public class ApiCallResult<X> where X : class
    {
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string ReasonPhrase { get; set; }

        public bool IsError { get; set; }
        public bool IsException { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public X ResponseObject { get; set; } //deserialized object, could be List, int string or just a single object
    }


   public static class ApiCrudCallHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Performs Post and returns ApiCallResult
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">model to Post, could be null, T, List T</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="X">return model by API, could be X, List X, string </typeparam>
        /// <param name="data">data to post of type T, List T</param>
        /// <param name="apiUrl">api full URL like http://localhost:65152/API/Test if executing custom action, provide that as well at the end </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// ApiCallResult
        ///     StatusCode: status code returned by the API
        ///     ReasonPhrase: reason phrase returned by the API
        ///     IsError: true/false
        ///     IsException: true/false
        ///     Message: error message, exception message, or result of OK etc results by API
        ///     X ResponseObject: model returned by the API, it might not be available in all cases. Could be X, List X or string as provided by X above
        /// </returns>
        public static async Task<ApiCallResult<X>> Post<T, X>(T data, string apiUrl) where X : class
        {
            var apiCallResult = new ApiCallResult<X> { IsError = true, Message = "No run" };
            try
            {
                //json string 
                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, httpContent);
                    var jsonResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //fill
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //deserialize
                        if (!typeof(X).Equals(typeof(string)))
                        {
                            apiCallResult.ResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(jsonResponseString);
                        }
                        apiCallResult.IsError = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ApiErrorMessage myMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiErrorMessage>(jsonResponseString);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myMessage?.Message))
                            {
                                jsonResponseString = myMessage.Message;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {}
                        jsonResponseString = jsonResponseString.Trim('"');
                    }
                    apiCallResult.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    apiCallResult.ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
                    apiCallResult.Message = jsonResponseString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                apiCallResult.IsException = true;
                apiCallResult.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return apiCallResult;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs Put and returns ApiCallResult
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">model to Post, could be null, T, List T</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="X">return model by API, could be X, List X, string </typeparam>
        /// <param name="data">data to post of type T, List T</param>
        /// <param name="apiUrl">api full URL including the Id like http://localhost:65152/API/Test/12345 if executing custom action, provide that as well </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// ApiCallResult
        ///     HttpStatusCode StatusCode: status code returned by the API
        ///     string ReasonPhrase: reason phrase returned by the API
        ///     bool IsError: true/false
        ///     bool IsException: true/false
        ///     string Message: error message, exception message, or result of OK etc results by API
        ///     X ResponseObject: model returned by the API, it might not be available in all cases. Could be X, List X or string as provided by X above
        /// </returns>
        public static async Task<ApiCallResult<X>> Put<T, X>(T data, string apiUrl) where X : class
        {
            var apiCallResult = new ApiCallResult<X> { IsError = true, Message = "No run" };
            try
            {
                //json string 
                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await client.PutAsync(apiUrl, httpContent);
                    var jsonResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //fill
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //deserialize
                        if (!typeof(X).Equals(typeof(string)))
                        {
                            apiCallResult.ResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(jsonResponseString);
                        }
                        apiCallResult.IsError = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ApiErrorMessage myMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiErrorMessage>(jsonResponseString);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myMessage?.Message))
                            {
                                jsonResponseString = myMessage.Message;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        { }
                        jsonResponseString = jsonResponseString.Trim('"');
                    }
                    apiCallResult.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    apiCallResult.ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
                    apiCallResult.Message = jsonResponseString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                apiCallResult.IsException = true;
                apiCallResult.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return apiCallResult;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs Delete and returns ApiCallResult
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="X">return model by API, could be X, List X, string. Usually you'll only get Ok result etc for delete, so specify string  </typeparam>
        /// <param name="apiUrl">api full URL including the Id like http://localhost:65152/API/Test/12345 if executing custom action, provide that as well </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// ApiCallResult
        ///     HttpStatusCode StatusCode: status code returned by the API
        ///     string ReasonPhrase: reason phrase returned by the API
        ///     bool IsError: true/false
        ///     bool IsException: true/false
        ///     string Message: error message, exception message, or result of OK etc results by API
        ///     X ResponseObject: will only be available if api is returning a model (should not), in most cases it will not be available. Could be X, List X or string as provided by X above
        /// </returns>
        public static async Task<ApiCallResult<X>> Delete<X>(string apiUrl) where X : class
        {
            var apiCallResult = new ApiCallResult<X> { IsError = true, Message = "No run" };
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response = await client.DeleteAsync(apiUrl);
                    var jsonResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //fill
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //deserialize
                        if (!typeof(X).Equals(typeof(string)))
                        {
                            apiCallResult.ResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(jsonResponseString);
                        }
                        apiCallResult.IsError = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ApiErrorMessage myMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiErrorMessage>(jsonResponseString);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myMessage?.Message))
                            {
                                jsonResponseString = myMessage.Message;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        { }
                        jsonResponseString = jsonResponseString.Trim('"');
                    }
                    apiCallResult.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    apiCallResult.ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
                    apiCallResult.Message = jsonResponseString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                apiCallResult.IsException = true;
                apiCallResult.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return apiCallResult;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs Get and returns ApiCallResult
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="X">return model by API, could be X, List X, string. </typeparam>
        /// <param name="apiUrl">api full URL </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// ApiCallResult
        ///     HttpStatusCode StatusCode: status code returned by the API
        ///     string ReasonPhrase: reason phrase returned by the API
        ///     bool IsError: true/false
        ///     bool IsException: true/false
        ///     string Message: error message, exception message, or result of OK etc results by API
        ///     X ResponseObject: Could be X, List X or string as provided by X above
        /// </returns>
        public static async Task<ApiCallResult<X>> Get<X>(string apiUrl) where X : class
        {
            var apiCallResult = new ApiCallResult<X> { IsError = true, Message = "No run" };
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
                    var jsonResponseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //fill
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //deserialize
                        if (!typeof(X).Equals(typeof(string)))
                        {
                            apiCallResult.ResponseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<X>(jsonResponseString);
                        }
                        apiCallResult.IsError = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ApiErrorMessage myMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiErrorMessage>(jsonResponseString);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myMessage?.Message))
                            {
                                jsonResponseString = myMessage.Message;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        { }
                        jsonResponseString = jsonResponseString.Trim('"');
                    }
                    apiCallResult.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    apiCallResult.ReasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
                    apiCallResult.Message = jsonResponseString;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                apiCallResult.IsException = true;
                apiCallResult.Message = ex.Message;
            }

            return apiCallResult;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes worked...

1. Had to change the process sub to Function
2. In Main introduced .Wait()

   Module EDIDownloaderModule

   ```
   Sub Main(args As String())
       ProcessApi().Wait()
   End Sub

   Private Async Function ProcessApi() As Task(Of Boolean)
       Dim isRun As Boolean =  Await TestHelper.ProcessApi()
       Return isRun
   End Function
   ```

   End Module